# How to implement soap-webservices without XML in Spring with CXF?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm looking for advise on the following requirement:

I'd like to write a webservice that works with `Spring`, maybe uses `CXF` (if it makes sense). I want to stick to pure annotation based configuration in Spring, no XML should be written.

I've done annotation based clients with sping already, but somehow I cannot find any good tutorial how to do the same as a soap service.
It also should be a contract-last service, so that I can auto-generate the WSDL from my Request/Response classes.

Further I'd like to have to configure my Req/Rsp classes as less as possible. Ideally I'd just write them as POJOs wrapping the data to transfer by soap, and that's it.

Could you point me which frameworks I should/could use for my approach?

Comment: CXF is ideal for that; no contract necessary, just use your JAXB-annotated POJOs and you will have a functional service. At least one xml configuration is required for using CXF: the *cxf-servlet.xml* file, which is a standard requirement for any JAX-WS-based web service framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it turned out that I can mainly stick to annotation based configuration, but the following xml is required:

```
<jaxws:endpoint implementor="de.MyService" address="/MyService" />
```